# ntpdate - no server suitable for synchronization found

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I am working on ntp. I have to connect to some external NTP server to get my system date updated. The issue is that ntpd Daemon is always using my local clock (127.127.1.0) and it is not using the NTP server that I have provided in ntp.conf. I am using 123.108.225.6 as NTP server and I am able to ping this IP. For the purpose of testing i executed ntpdate but i got the following result.

```
[root@commander_a ~]# sudo ntpdate -dv 123.108.225.6
18 Nov 06:11:47 ntpdate[4781]: ntpdate 4.2.6p3@1.2290 Fri Aug 28 07:43:22 UTC 2015 (1)
Looking for host 123.108.225.6 and service ntp
host found : 123.108.225.6
transmit(123.108.225.6)
transmit(123.108.225.6)
transmit(123.108.225.6)
transmit(123.108.225.6)
transmit(123.108.225.6)
123.108.225.6: Server dropped: no data
server 123.108.225.6, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [123.108.225.6], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 18:00:00.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 18:00:00.000
transmit timestamp:  d9f6e989.bbb84d5f  Wed, Nov 18 2015  6:11:53.733
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

18 Nov 06:11:55 ntpdate[4781]: no server suitable for synchronization found
[root@commander_a ~]# ^C
```

I find it strange that "originate timestamp" it is taking some old time. It is not my local system time.

### originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 18:00:00.000

### ntp.conf

disable stats
server  123.108.225.6 
server  127.127.1.0 # local clock
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 10

### driftfile /etc/ntp/drift

I have spent lot of time finding the solution, But i didnt succeeded. 
Please help me !!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29418250/3788685) Q&A may assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if your internet service provider is blocking port 123.

Make sure there isn't an external firewall between the machine and the rest of the internet. If there is, request that the people administering the firewall open port 123.

Answer (score 3):

This website maybe helpful  to  you
[ntpdate: no server suitable for synchronization found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429306/ntpdate-no-server-suitable-for-synchronization-found)

I use this command  to  modify the  date

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

Comment: Very nice. Great workaround when you have firewall you do not control in a complex network of servers.

Answer (score 0):

> ### You must use a UDP port (not TCP)

I had the same issue. I opened TCP port 123 bi-direction and it did NOT work. Turns out you specifically need a UDP port, as NTP does not run on TCP by default.

Hope this helps someone, I lost over an hour because of this subtlety.

Answer (score 0):

For me same issue, we found firewall blocking the traffic. We modified rules and started working.

Cheers !!