# Behavior of chronyd when time cannot be synchronized

Tags: centos, centos7, ntp

How does chronyd work when it changes from a state where the time is synchronized to the server whose name is resolved from the pool to a state where communication with the server is lost?

CentOS 7

```
# chronyd -v
chronyd (chrony) version 1.29.1

# grep server /etc/chrony.conf
# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
server 0.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.amazon.pool.ntp.org iburst
# Serve time even if not synchronized to any NTP server.
```

Time was not synchronized

```
# chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 4
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? 45.76.218.213.vultr.com       2  10     0  518d  -6679us[-6905us] +/-   40ms
^? v150-95-148-140.a08d.g.ty     2  10     0  745d  -105.4s[ +315us] +/-   47ms
^? 45.76.98.188.vultr.com        3  10     0  564d  +1031ms[ -242us] +/-  209ms
^? 153-128-30-125.compute.jp     2  10     0  748d  -108.1s[-2427us] +/-   37ms
```

Comment: Looks like your security settings may be blocking, or at least not allowing port 123. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418250) may help you with some diagnostics etc.